# how to set a value of a dropdown to that value having a class as "selected"-Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the value in a dropdown who has a classname = "selected".
here is the html:

```
 <select style="width:180px;" class="chosen-select" id="range">
<option value="7 days">7days</option>
<option value="20days" class="selected">20days</option>
<option value="30days">30days</option>
</select>
```

now here is what im trying to work out:
js:

```
 $("#range_select").find('option.selected'); //gives me:
     <option value="20days" class="selected">20days</option>
```

below is a psedo code:

```
 if($("#range_select").find('option').hasClass("selected")){
    //set the value of the dropdown to "20days"
   //currently showing the default value "7days"
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xwo10r7k/

how can i achieve this? Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
 $("#range").find('option.selected').attr("selected","selected");
```

updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xwo10r7k/1/

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/0v0e24m3/)***

Store the range element, use it as a parent to find the class, and then set the range element's value as the child's value

```
var $r = $("#range");
$r.val($(".selected",$r).val());
```